# Add struct in std::list

Tags: c++, iterator, find, stdlist

I have a following struct:

```cpp
struct data {
    std::string str;
    int num;
    int num2;
    std::string str2
} data1;
```

I have a `std::list<struct data> list`;

I want to add struct in `std::list`, assuming there is no such structure, use `std::find_if` and lambda function's.

```cpp
std::list<data>::iterator it = std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), data1);
if (it == list.end()) list.push_back(data1)
```

How can you do this?

Comment: I added a solution to my answer, see if it works for you.

Comment: I do it, but i want to use std::find_if and lambda function's

Comment: @ivanovIAVDD Is it a requirement to use `find_if` and a lambda?

Comment: You could use a `std::set` if you supply a hashing function and `operator==`.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, yes, i have to use find_if and a lambda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `std::find_if` and a lambda:

```
std::list<data>::iterator it = std::find_if(list.begin(), list.end(),
    [&data1](const data& rhs) {
        return
            data1.str == rhs.str &&
            data1.num == rhs.num &&
            data1.num2 == rhs.num2 &&
            data1.str2 == rhs.str2;
    }
);
```

---

In this case I would however recommend defining `data::operator==` and using `std::find` instead:

```
struct data {
    std::string str;
    int num;
    int num2;
    std::string str2;

    bool operator==(const data& rhs) const {
        return
            str == rhs.str &&
            num == rhs.num &&
            num2 == rhs.num2 &&
            str2 == rhs.str2;
    }
};

std::list<data>::iterator it = std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), data1);
```

in C++20, you can simplify this by defaulting [`operator<=>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons) (the *spaceship operator*):

> *a defaulted `<=>` overload will also allow the type to be compared with `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=`. If `operator<=>` is defaulted and `operator==` is not declared at all, then `operator==` is implicitly defaulted.*

Given that, here's how to allow `data` to be compared using all those operators:

```
struct data {
    std::string str;
    int num;
    int num2;
    std::string str2;

    friend auto operator<=>(const data&, const data&) = default;
};
```

Comment: Ahhh... the spaceship operator, excelent adition.

Comment: @anastaciu I can't say that I've fully understood all it can be used for and haven't actually used it in any of my own programs yet  :-) It seems really versatile though.

Comment: As all new things, time is needed to settle it. I didn't even remeber it before you mentioned it. I also find it quite interesting.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate the list and compare the object you want to add with existing objects, you do it by comparing all data memebers, if they match then the objects are equal. I would advise the implementation a custom comparison operator, instead of comparing data members every time you need to compare objects:

```cpp
struct data
{
    std::string str;
    int num;
    int num2;
    std::string str2;

    bool operator==(const data &d)
    {
        return this->num == d.num && this->str == d.str && this->num2 == d.num2 && d.str2 == this->str2;
    }
};
```

For usage with lambda and `std::find_if()`:

```
data d{"string1", 2, 2, "string2"}; 

std::list<data>::iterator it = std::find_if(list.begin(), list.end(), [&](const data& dt) {
    return d == dt;         
});

if(it == list.end())
{
    list.push_back(d);
}
```

Note that, as [@Remy pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67174450/add-struct-in-stdlist/67174639#comment118739508_67174639) in the comment section, this can be more easily achieved using `std::find()` instead of `std::find_if()`:

```
std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), d); // comparator implementation also needed
```

Comment: Note that with `operator==` implemented, it is possible to use `std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), d)` instead of `std::find_if()`, no lambda needed. I know that is not the requirement, but it should be noted.

Comment: @RemyLebeau noted, I linked the comment, please don't delete it.

Comment: Thank you! I use a std::find.

Answer (score 0):

You did not declare the `std::list` properly. Make sure to only specify the data type. In this case, the declaration should have been `std::list<data> list;`.

Afterwards you can create objects of type `data` and store them inside the `std::list` using `push_back`.

Comment: The `struct` keyword in `std::list<struct data> list` is valid but not required in this case (the lookup c++ can determine that `data` refers to the `struct`). If you - in addition - would also have a function with the name `data` then the `struct` keyword would be required.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out @t.niese, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Before adding, I want to check if such item exists in the list